# Creating a reset password link when user enter his/her email

Tags: html, debugging, asp-classic

when the user forgot her/his password, they enter their email and there will be a reset password link. How do I create a href="" link or reset link in .HTMLBody CDO.Message? is in line 50. If there is a better way let me know. I'm really appreciate the help.

```html
<!-- 
    METADATA 
    TYPE="typelib" 
    UUID="CD000000-8B95-11D1-82DB-00C04FB1625D"  
    NAME="CDO for Windows 2000 Library" 
--> 

    <%
    DIM strEmail
    strEmail = Request.Form("email")

    IF strEmail <> "" THEN
    
    %>
    
    <%
    DIM objDB, rs, rssql
    Set objDB = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    objDB.Open "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Password=langas;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=mmsg;Data Source=mmsg_web"
    rssql = "SELECT email_addr, medacist_password FROM medacist_user WHERE email_addr = '" & strEmail & "'"
    Set rs = objDB.Execute(rssql) 


    IF rs.EOF THEN
    Response.Write "That email address was not found in our database. Please click Back on your browser and enter the email address you registered with."
    ELSE
    DIM strPassword, rs_link
    set strPassword = rs("medacist_password")
    

    Set cdoConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")  
 
    With cdoConfig.Fields  
        .Item(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort  
        .Item(cdoSMTPServer) = "10.1.1.186"  'Ongoing sever SMTP required \\'
  ''      .Item(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = 1'
    ''    .Item(cdoSendUsername) ="<enter_username>"
    ' '   .Item(cdoSendPassword) ="<enter_password>"''
        .Update  
    End With 
 
    Set cdoMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")  
 
    With cdoMessage 
        Set .Configuration = cdoConfig 
        .From = "email@email.com" 
        .To = strEmail 
        .Subject = "Forgotten Password IP TextBody" 
        .HTMLBody = "Please click below link to reset your password: <br>" 
        .Send 
    End With 
 
    Set cdoMessage = Nothing  
    Set cdoConfig = Nothing  


    Response.Write "Your password has been sent to your email address."
    END IF

    ELSE
    Response.Write "Please click Back on your browser and enter the email address you registered with."
    END IF
    %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add  in you body, may be this will help you:-

```
.HTMLBody = "Please click below link to reset your password: <br> <a href='http://yourresetpassword.html'>Click this link to reset your password</a>"
```

Comment: Thanks, when I click on the link it goes to www.change_password.asp instead go to the file directory why is that?

Comment: Can you show what is then link path you want to open when user click

Comment: It works if I add the http in front with the website link. But now it doesn't let me reset the password. When I click on that link it suppose to retype all the password and confirm. Now is just asking to login again.

Comment: it is because of your code, may be you are validating something and on fails redirect to login page

Comment: does it normally put a http://resetfilelink for user to click on and reset? and what code does it required to validate that he/she is the user.

Comment: I did able to view the password with SQL code but the password is encrypted with @#^^@%#^@%#^@ symbols how do I able to request the string variable?

Comment: you are mixing multiple things at once, think first

Comment: I wish I could, I'm new with ASP CLASSIC, help me think :D